# Oracle Avg Number of Calls Per Hour By Year

Tags: sql, oracle

I have an Oracle table filled with call information.  I have the call datetime field (calldate).  Each record represents one call.  How do I find the average number of calls per hour by year?

Sample data: 
Calldate                               Account     Name
1/20/2016 10:16:09 AM          12345          Blee 
 
1/20/2016 11:17:02 AM          45678            Foo

Something like:

1:00 AM 23  
2:00 AM 22  
3:00 AM 19

Thank you!

Comment: please show some sample data as well.

Comment: we need full row samples.

Comment: See edit for sample data

Comment: Standard AVG using `TO_CHAR` or `EXTRACT` to get the year/hour.

Comment: Can you please show me an example using the information I have provided?

Comment: What does year have to do with the question?

Comment: I want the data further separated by year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
select to_char(calldate, 'YYYY-HH24') as yyyyhh,
       count(*) / count(distinct trunc(calldate)) as avg_per_hour
from t
group by to_char(calldate, 'YYYY-HH24')
order by yyyyhh;
```

Note:  This treats days with no calls as `NULL`, rather than zero.